# Free Android library to display tiles

Tags: tiles, android

I have a set of tiles for a certain area, I have to load them in the client, and draw some points,lines on the tiles.

Generally there are some opensource android library like osmdroid, mapsforge and etc to load the tiles , however the tiles I am working with are not generated by the common projection like `EPSG4326` or `EPSG3857`.

They are generated by Arcgis Server, with a custom coordination system, I can get the tile origin, resolution of each zoom, I can load the tiles by openlayers(because ol support custom resolutions) but I can not load them by the popular library since none of them support the custom srs.

At the moment, the only choice is the Arcgis Android SDK, while it is huge, with almost 30M which I tried to avoid.

Is there other alternative solution?

Comment: The nutiteq SDK claims to support arbitrary map projections. I do not have experience with it, so can't really provide an example of using tiles in another projection, so that is something that you'll have to explore. Do note that it is not a free library, and you need to purchase a license.

Comment: Thanks, I know nutiteq SDK, it is out of my consideration is exact the license. :)

Comment: vector tiles or raster tiles? would you be OK with having the client reprojecting on the fly or do you want to show the coordinates "as is"?

Comment: Raster tiles supporting is enough. The tiles is generated by a certain projection, just display them "as is"